# How can we reconcile 1 Timothy 6 & Exodus 24?

Tags: contradiction, exodus, 1-timothy

1 Timothy 6

> [16]who alone possesses immortality and dwells in unapproachable light, whom ***no man has seen or can see***. To Him be honor and eternal dominion! Amen.

Exodus 24:10-11

> [10]***and they saw the God of Israel***; and under His feet there appeared to be a pavement of sapphire, as clear as the sky itself.
>   [11]Yet He did not stretch out His hand against the nobles of the sons of Israel; and they saw God, and they ate and drank.

It seems Moses & Aaron & the seventy elders saw a visible form,a similitude since they mention a paved work of sapphire stone under his feet but Paul says no man has seen,God,  So how can we understand the contradiction in the above texts,

Comment: It might be thought that because this Q invokes 1 Tim 6:16, that's sufficient to prevent it from being a duplicate. That's not my sense. Ex 24:10-11 makes an unusual claim which could be similarly contrasted with many biblical texts. We don't need such questions proliferating when they're essentially dealing with the same issue.

Comment: @David unfortunately at times the duplicate question does not pop up because of the difference in phrasing so one does not notice that the Q has already been asked,thank you

Comment: I can see how that would be an issue. But have you [tried searching](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/search?q=) for your texts and key terms before posting your own question? Perhaps you have! If not, that would be a worthwhile bit of "research" to do before posting new Q's.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion:

God is a destructive energy (Heb. 12:29) living in an unapproachable light (1Tim. 6:16). This light is so powerful that it surely could burn the human body if one is put into the position to see this.

What they so? They so God incarnated into a human-like body. This is like human body of Christ. The disciples saw human body of Christ, but they never so Christ himself every existing at the heaven.

In short: God himself cannot be seen but his incarnation can.

Comment: Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please [edit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/27744/edit) to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Also, please see [what we’re looking for in answers](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/533/2215). This doesn't [show its work](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/846/423), which is a [requirement](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/777/423) on this site.